# Why was PHP 7.3 automatically installed on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, server, php7

I have been trying to figure out a problem with a Ubuntu 16.04 server for a while and recently found that the problem is that php 7.3 seems to have been automatically installed during a "apt-get update ; apt-get -y dist-upgrade" on October 15, 2018 so that the system started to use php 7.3 instead of php 7.1 that was already installed.

On August 2, 2018, I had these php related packages installed according to `dpkg -l|grep php|grep -v ^rc` (I have a saved output of "dpkg -l" from that date):

```
libapache2-mod-php7.1  
php-apcu  
php-common  
php7.1  
php7.1-cli  
php7.1-common  
php7.1-curl  
php7.1-gd  
php7.1-intl  
php7.1-json  
php7.1-mbstring  
php7.1-mysql  
php7.1-opcache  
php7.1-readline  
php7.1-soap  
php7.1-xml  
php7.1-xmlrpc  
php7.1-zip
```

If I compare with a saved output of `dpkg -l` from August 2, 2018, and today February 4, 2019, I see that I now have these additionally php packages installed:

```
libphp7.3-embed  
php7.3-cli  
php7.3-common  
php7.3-json  
php7.3-opcache  
php7.3-readline
```

The log from `apt-get update ; apt-get -y dist-upgrade` on October 15, 2018, looks like this:

```
[...]  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
libargon2-0 libpcre2-8-0 libphp7.3-embed libsodium23 php7.3-cli
php7.3-common php7.3-json php7.3-opcache php7.3-readline  
The following packages will be upgraded:  
libapache2-mod-php7.1 php-apcu php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-curl
php7.1-gd php7.1-intl php7.1-json php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mysql
php7.1-opcache php7.1-readline php7.1-soap php7.1-xml php7.1-xmlrpc
php7.1-zip python-requests python3-requests  
19 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
[...]
```

I would like to figure out why those php 7.3 related packages where automatically installed on October 15, 2018. Any idea?

Comment: Neither php7.1 nor php7.3 is in the Ubuntu 16.04 repositories, so I see two likely culprits: 1) Whatever non-Ubuntu sources your system is using, and 2) The (mis-)use of `dist-upgrade` instead of `full-upgrade`. The latter would have retained 7.1, Also, the (mis)use of the -y flag disabled your ability to review and abort the changes at the time.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm using ppa:ondrej/php (deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main). I still wonder how php7.3 was able to be automatically install. What dependency did cause that? (php7.1 was not uninstalled when php7.3 was installed by dist-upgrade - the problem was that when php7.3 was installed then it did automatically update the symlink /etc/alternatives/php)

Comment: Is this a VPS 'server'?  If you have a VPS that has Apache or PHP already installed it'd have just 'upgraded' when you add the PPA, and it's not uncommon to see VPS providers preinstall 'commonly sought after' software sets like Apache and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A *reverse dependency* apt query will tell you which packages depend upon a package. This is the inverse of a normal dependency search.

Example: Package `foo` depends upon package `libfoo1`.

```
$ apt-cache depends foo
foo
  Depends: libfoo1

$ apt-cache rdepends libfoo1
libfoo1
Reverse Depends:
  foo
```

In 16.04 and newer systems, you can use either `apt` or `apt-cache` to do the query. Syntax is identical.

Do a reverse dependency search upon those php7.3 packages to find what pulled them in.

Comment: Thanks. I've done a reverse dependency search for all of the php7.3  packages installed in the system, but none of them shows any connection from other non-php7.3-packages that are installed in the system, e.g., I see that libapache2-mod-php7.3 depends on some of them, but libapache2-mod-php7.3 is not installed.

Comment: If nothing uses the 7.3 packages, then try removing them...and see what breaks. Or just carefully read the apt output to see what *will* break if you proceed. Or use the --simulate flag to see what *would* break. Personally, I think dist-upgrade calculated the change based on the digits in the package name. It can do that, you know - it's intended use is to cleverly rejuggle whole dependency chains (exactly like this) during a Debian distribution upgrade.